# How can send values of drop down option on submit button while using WHILE LOOP?

Tags: php

I am using while loop e.g

```
while($work=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){?>
<td><?php echo $work['location']; ?></td>
<td><form method="post"><select name="title">
    <?php
    while($task=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){?>
 <option><?php echo $task['title']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select></td>

<td><input type="submit" name="submit"><td>

</form>
<?php }?>
```

While i am sending $_POST['title'] using:

1: header("location:assign.php?id=$work['id']&title=$_POST['title']");

2: Or using JS header document.location.href='assign.php?id=$work['id']&title=$_POST['title']';

It only send 'id' not title ..

Please tell me about how to send title that comes from drop down list...

Comment: No idea what you’re asking. Show us _proper_ code for the part where the actual problem lies - not just those one-liners without any context. For example the header line, if taken as shown by you, would only produce a syntax error. This whole thin looks like you should perhaps go read up on how to use strings properly ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your  tags a value.
Change this line:

```
<option><?php echo $task['title']; ?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $task['title']; ?>"><?php echo $task['title']; ?></option>
```

Edit: This is wrong. I didn't realize that empty  values would have a default/fall back. Leaving the answer up so no one makes the same mistake.

Comment: _“You need to give your <option> tags a value”_ – no, you don’t; if no value is explicitly given, the content of the option automatically becomes the submission value.